# Issues with ScrollMagic and GreenSock on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, gsap, scrollmagic

I am doing an animation with `ScrollMagic` and `GreenSock`'s `TimelineMax`. The animation is suppose to go in a `WordPress` page. However the animation has some glitches when the page is open in Chrome. This problem does not occur in Safari and Firefox. I can't test for IE.

This is how the problem looks like: [image: Scroll Magic Animation]

And this is how it is suppose to look like: [image]

The most bottom part with title **Your web site** goes up, and the two top parts move down. As I said, it works perfect on Safari and Firefox, but on Chrome you have to scroll up and down to fix the issue. However this is not acceptable for us, since the users of our page wont see the animation properly when they first scroll down.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/y0pnqo33/) is JSFiddle of the animation. Now, this will most probably work without problems in JSFiddle, but when I put this in WordPress page it looks like on the first image. Does anybody have a clue why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) I don't want to delete the question, because I hope somebody will find it useful.

The solution is to increase the `z-index` of all the elements (images, divs, everywhere where I have z-index in the css.). I increased it for 1000 on every element and it worked.